# Reduced row echelon form of full rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Does the row echelon form of a full rank square matrix ALWAYS reduce to identity matrix? Thanks

Comment: Yes. The pivot columns always become columns of the identity in the RREF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a square matrix has a full rank, then it is invertible. And any invertible matrix can be reduced to the identity matrix by a finite sequence of elementary row operations.